# Wires reach into European resistors in CircuiTikZ

Tags: circuitikz

I've drawn a simple circuit diagram with [CircuiTikZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CircuiTikZ), but my wires do somehow reach into my resistors which doesn't look very pretty. I guess this is quite easy to fix, but I couldn't do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[european,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,2) to[open,v=$u_q(t)$] (0,0);
    \draw (0,2) to[short,o-] (1,2);
    \draw (1,2) to[R, l=$R$, v>=$u_R(t)$] (2,2);
    \draw (2,2) -- (3,2);
    \draw (3,2) to[L, l=$L$,v>=$u_{ind}(t)$] (4,2);
    \draw (4,2) -- (5,2);
    \draw (5,2) to[short,i=$i(t)$] (5,0);
    \draw (0,0) to[short,o-] (5,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The main problem here (to clarify a bit) is that the distance between `(1,2)` and `(2,2)` is `(1,0)`, and with default Ti*k*Z settings that is 1cm. By default, the resistor is bigger... You can scale every component [see the manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#paragraph.3.1.4.1) for example with `\ctikzset{bipoles/length=.8cm}`.

Comment: In other words, instead of extending into the resistor, you are starting inside the resistor and extending out to the anchors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are overdrawing the wire into the "R" component by the code

```
      \draw (0,2) to[short,o-] (1,2);
```

Have a look now:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[european,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,2) to[open,v=$u_q(t)$] (0,0);
    \draw (0,2) to[short,o-] (0,2);
    \draw (0,2) to[R, l=$R$, v>=$u_R(t)$] (2,2);
    \draw (2,2) -- (3,2);
    \draw (3,2) to[L, l=$L$,v>=$u_{ind}(t)$] (4,2);
    \draw (4,2) -- (5,2);
    \draw (5,2) to[short,i=$i(t)$] (5,0);
    \draw (0,0) to[short,o-] (5,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

**With relative positioning you will not go wrong** -- will give the same result

And avoid overlap of wire into the inductor ("L") also:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[european,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,2) to [open,v=$u_q(t)$]            (0,0);
    \draw (0,2) to [short,o-]                   ++(0,0)
                to [R, l=$R$, v>=$u_R(t)$]      ++(2,0)
                to [L, l=$L$,v>=$u_{ind}(t)$]   ++(3,0)
                to [short]                      ++(0.5,0)
                to [short,i=$i(t)$]             ++(0,-2)
                to                              (0,0)
                to [short,o-]                   (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: oh right I see, thank you for the very comprehensive answer! I think you have a tiny mistake in your code which makes the wire coming from the resistor reach into the node on the top left

Comment: please see the edit above

Comment: @MS the glitch with the pole is explained in the second example about poles in the manual: https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#subsection.6.1